# how to get all href link from html inside ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

In my script getting all the href link script is not working inside ajax i am using angular cli for my project.how we can rosolve this issue.

```
        $.ajax({
        url:"assets/myfiles/test.html",
        type:'GET',
        async: false,
        success: function(data){

                $('#page').html(data);   
                var links = $('#page a');
                var title = $('#page a').attr('title');   
                var arr=[];
                for(var i=0; i < links.length; i++)
                {
                    arr.push(links[i]); 
                } 
                alert(arr);

              }
              });
```

test.html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>  
  <a href="test.html" title="test">123</a>
  <a href="test1.html" title="test2">1234</a>

  <a href="test4.html" title="tedfhdfhst">12345</a>
  <a href="test5.html" title="tesdfhdfhdfht2">123456</a>

  <a href="test7.html" title="tedfhdfhst">1234567</a>
  <a href="test8.html" title="tesdfhdfhdfht2">234</a>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: i suggest not to set async to false

Comment: Is your array containing any links or what is the problem?! Assuming the returned `data` from your test.html is a valid HTML string and contains some links.

Comment: Is success definitely firing (i.e. no request errors)? Can you console.log(data) and show us what we're actually getting back?

Comment: i am getting html data but i am not getting href link from the data. array is empty in my console

Comment: Your code seems to be working absolutely fine. Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8odkjwq8/).

Comment: Your code is working when you set `async: true`, otherwise the browser might block the request...

Comment: Don't include `<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  </head>
  <body> ` and `</body>
  </html>` the index.html that you download. Just have it as a snippet with only the links. It's not really valid to insert a whole other HTML document inside an element within the main page. Some browsers will tolerate it, but it's not really part of the spec and not guaranteed. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html says that `<html>` is "the root element. All other elements must be descendants of this element." So it being a child of a div is not valid

Comment: Not saying that's the cause of your issue, but it's not a sensible thing to do.

Comment: Nice..working. but small issue coming...if i use https://www.google.co.in i an getting https://localhost:8080/mail/?tab=wm, instead of https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab..why i am getting like that?

Comment: what do you mean "if i use google.co.in", exactly? Are you trying to download the contents of google's home page into your own page? Why? I would guess the problem with the Gmail link is there because the URL google uses is relative (to the server it's hosted on) and not absolute.